# Get the selected option from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I'm trying to get the selected option via jQuery everytime I change it, and eventually the value attribute, buy I always have problems with js!!

HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="us">United States</option>
    <option value="gb">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="de" selected="selected">Germany</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$("select").change (function () {
    // what can I do there?
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$("select").change (function () {
  var selectedValue = $("select").val();

  var selectedText = $("select:selected").text();
});
```

Comment: Since the value of a select is the value of the selected option, you don't need the ":selected" -- $("select").val() is sufficient.

Comment: You would need a space between the `select` and the `:selected`. It is the `option` element that can have the `:selected` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 1):

`$("select").val()` will always give you the value of the selected option at any point.